# Project Only -> Clean Only Project is cleaning other project in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have multiple projects in the same solution. Two of them are in the same directory (and therefore share a debug directory). When I clean either project, obj and lib files for both are deleted. This didn't happen in Visual Studio 2008.

There is an asymmetry since after I clean one project, it only detects that project as out of date, and when I build there are linker errors since the other project's obj files aren't there.

Is there a way to fix this so only the files associated with the cleaned project are deleted?

Comment: Did you make one project depend on another on VS?

Comment: @billz, Let's call the two projects A and B. A has B as a dependency. B does not have A as a dependency. However, cleaning either one cleans both. Also, project A has one other project as a dependency (project C), and cleaning project A never cleans project C. So I'm not sure if dependencies have anything to do with it. The pattern seems to be that any projects with project files in the same directory get cleaned together.

Answer (score 2):

You have to setup different intermediate directories for your two projects in a single directory. Otherwise a clean on a single project wipes all files of both projects.